# While add firesbase via cmd $flutter pub add firebase_auth, the file generated_plugin_registrant.dart shows error (in Red color)

Tags: firebase

In generated_plugin_registrant.dart file
Only for this thing have no error. If the "_web" lines are comes when I install firebase via cmd

```
void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {
  FirebaseCoreWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  registrar.registerMessageHandler();
}
```

Comment: in pubspec.yaml, firebase_auth version changed to firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5 and save, Then solved my problem